# Atualizar label em loop

Tags: java, loop, javafx, fxml

Como faço pra atualizar um label em um loop na aba `FXMLDocumentController`?
Os labels só atualizam depois que finaliza todo o loop e então joga a ultima informação na tela;

```
package musicaisfx;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.PaintEvent;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    String frase = "bbb " ;
    @FXML
   private void playBotao(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {


       char letras[] = frase.toCharArray();
       for (int i = 0 ;i < letras.length; i++) {
           label.setText("b");
              frase=frase+frase;     
           Font name=Font.getFont("LASSUS");
           label.setStyle("-fx-font-family:Arial");
           label.setText(frase);
            Thread.sleep(500);




           System.out.println(frase);

       }

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o código possui somente uma thread. Quando o método `playBotao` é chamado, a tela fica bloqueada porque o método está executando na mesma thread da tela. Portanto, só depois que o método terminar de executar é que a tela conseguirá atualizar os seus componentes.

Para impedir que a tela fique bloqueada é necessário criar uma thread separada para executar a operação desejada. O javafx disponibiliza duas classes para trabalhar com threads: `Task` e `Service`. Para ler mais sobre essas duas classes e sobre concorrência no javafx, veja essa link: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

O método `playBotao` precisa executar em uma thread separada, dessa forma, enquanto o método está alterando o valor do label, a thread da GUI irá atualizar o label. Um detalhe importante é que somente a thread da GUI (comumente chamada de thread do javafx) pode alterar os componentes de tela. Isso acontece porque a GUI não é thread-safe e por isso ela não permite que outra thread altere os componentes da tela.

Se você colocar o conteúdo do método `playBotao` dentro de uma Task e mandar executar o código, será lançada uma exceção de: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread**. Para evitar esse erro, você precisa colocar a parte do código que altera componentes da tela, no caso a parte que muda o valor do label, dentro de um Runnable e passá-lo para o método `Platform.runLater(Runnable runnable)`. Esse método irá executar o código desejado na thread do javafx em algum ponto no futuro. Para esse caso, você verá que a solução funcionará bem. Segue exemplo de código:

```
private String frase = "bbb ";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
            Label label = new Label("João");
            Button button = new Button("Alterar Label");
            button.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>(){
                    @Override
                    protected Void call()  {

                        char letras[] = frase.toCharArray();
                        for (int i = 0 ;i < letras.length; i++) {
                            // Necessário para que não ocorra:
                            //java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread
                            //O trecho será executado na thread do javafx
                            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                                label.setText("b");
                                frase=frase+frase;     
                                label.setStyle("-fx-font-family:Arial");
                                label.setText(frase);

                            });
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(500);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            System.out.println(frase);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                Thread thread = new Thread(task);
                thread.setName("task-change-label");
                thread.setDaemon(true);
                thread.start();
            });

            gridPane.add(button, 0, 0);
            gridPane.add(label, 1, 0);

            Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane,400,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```